# Не получается передать данные из таблицы QTableWidget в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

У меня есть таблица, в которой хранятся какие-то данные. Эти данные мне надо передать в словарь, чтобы сохранить его в файле формата `json`.

Я использую строку `self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column).text()`, 
чтобы достать данные из таблицы, но у меня появляется ошибка:

> `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Вот весь код

```
def save(self):
        row_dict = {}
        row_list = []
        for column in range(self.ui.tableWidget.columnCount()):
            for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                value = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column).text()                
                row_list.append(str(value))
            row_dict[column] = row_list
            row_list = []
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Я не знаю какой еще пример можно дать. В этом куске ничто ни от чего не зависит. Мне нужно узнать как правильно достать данные из таблицы, чтоб не было ошибок.

Comment: Ошибка у вас из-за того, что метод QTableWidget.item возвращает None, а чтобы этого небыло надо в нужную ячейку  предварительно добавить QTableWidgetItem. Rtfm https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, метод QTableWidget.item возвращает мне `<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7f20111f59d0>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... чтобы не было ошибок, попробуйте так:

```
def save(self):
    row_dict = {}
    row_list = []
    for column in range(self.ui.tableWidget.columnCount()):
        for row in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        
#            value = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column).text()                
            value = self.ui.tableWidget.item(row, column) 
            if value is not None:
                row_list.append(value.text())
            else:
                row_list.append('')
            
        row_dict[column] = row_list
        row_list = []
```